# Unable to Set Dropdown List in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page that is allowing a user to select a state, city, and department from a drop down. Each drop down is populated based on the selected value of the previous drop down. When the user make a selection, I store the value in a cookie. Then, I check the cookie when the page load/reload. The page is reloaded and the value looks fine; however, I am not able to set the value on the drop down box. I tried hard coded the value, but it still does not work. Did I miss something?

```
   $(function () {
        var checkState = checkCookie("SelectedState"); // get the state index that was saved in the cookie.
        var cityDropdown = $('#CityName');
        if (checkState != "" && checkState != null) {
            var checkCityCookie = checkCookie("cityName"); // get the city index value
            var newCity = checkCityCookie.replace("=", " ")
            if (newCity == "") {
                getCity(checkState); //populate the city drop down
            }
            if (newCity  != null && newCity != "") {
                $('#CityName').val(1); //Hard code value here and still not working.
                var checkDepartment = checkCookie("SelectedDepartment");
                if (checkDepartment != null && checkDepartment != "") {
                    getDepartment(newCity);
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

**Updated 08/07/2014:**

```
//This is a sample of the html file that is generated, 
so there is a value 1. $('#CityName').val(1);

<select name="CityName" id="CityName" onchange="changeCityName()"><option value="">Choose School</option>
<option value="1">Miami</option>
<option value="2">West Palm</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Basic debugging time. Any errors in the console? Add some logging to your code with `console.log()` at the start of the function, in each of your `if..else` statements and `console.log('#CityName');` to see if you are actually targeting an object. Now check the console again and see if your expected log are happening. Also try `$('#CityName').val('1');` as the value is a string not an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have html like this:

```
<select id="ddl-my-cities">
    <option value="1">City 1</option>
    <option value="2">City 2</option>
    <option value="3">City 3</option>
    <option value="4">City 4</option>
</select>
```

current jQuery code should work:

```
$("#ddl-my-cities").val(3);
```

please, check your html. If it does not work for you, take a look to the console, probably you have an error.

if you have not errors in the console, please, provide your html or razor code and I will edit my answer.

Comment: It's kind of difficult to figure out what happens by using only a separate pieces of code... Anyway, 1) why you created and I do not use `cityDropdown` variable?, 2) What happens in the `getCity(checkState)` method? 3) Did you put breakpoint inside of `if (newCity  != null && newCity != "") {}`? I think something wrong is happening inside of `getCity(checkState)` and `(newCity  != null && newCity != "")` equals `false`

Comment: I've decided to do the validation on the server side instead of client side. I used a sessionwrapper to save the value of the search box, and I checked the value every time the page is reloaded. It does the trick for now.